# Framebuffer on OpenBSD?

Tags: terminal, openbsd, console, bsd, framebuffer

I am migrating from Linux to OpenBSD, and one of the things I miss from my old OS is how even the consoles looked nice (so nice you could actually watch movies in there) under framebuffer using a simple command on the bootloader. Is there any way I could do that on OpenBSD (creative/hard solutions are more than welcome)? If not, is there any way I could at least spawn some colors to the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

There is interesting project on github:

> === libfb-bsd === A console framebuffer graphics library for FreeBSD

https://github.com/p120ph37/libfb-bsd

Also, for FreeBSD, check ***handbook*** and ***man*** pages:

*FreeBSD Handbook/Chapter 4 UNIX Basics/4.2 Virtual Consoles and Terminals*
http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/consoles.html

All best,

vmisev

Comment: Sorry for the possibly stupid question, but is that portable to OpenBSD?